# How is threading.py calling showwarning?

Tags: python, warnings

I am trying to track down who is calling showwarning in the warnings module.

I set a breakpoint on showwarning and got the following callstack in PyCharm.

```
showwarning, warnings.py:12
run, threading.py:868
_bootstrap_inner, threading.py:920
_bootstrap, threading.py:888
```

The code of `run()` is:

```
def run(self):
    """Method representing the thread's activity.

    You may override this method in a subclass. The standard run() method
    invokes the callable object passed to the object's constructor as the
    target argument, if any, with sequential and keyword arguments taken
    from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.

    """
    try:
        if self._target:
            self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    finally:
        # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
        # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
        del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs
```

The actual call to `showwarning` is supposedly at the place where `self.target` is first called (under the `try`).  However, as you can see there is no such call in the actual source code.

My **Question**:  How is it that a call to `showwarning` is occurring when no call is there.  I've looked for 'warn' in threading.py or some kind of __enter__/__exit__ usage, but I've not seen anything.  How is it that Python injects the call to `showwarning` there?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

In case it's pertinent, all of this code is running under a Python unittest (i.e. import unittest, run test and showwarning() is called)

Comment: Sounds like what would happen if the thread's target is a C function. C functions don't show up in Python stack traces.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  In this case the target function is a plane ol' Python function.  Any other ideas?